# Finding elements with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a script that is **scraping** some data. When I have a table with each information in each line, the loop in my script is ok using [{i+1}] to read xpath in the different lines.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWN26.png)

```
elements = browser.find_elements_by_id('VisualizarDocumento')
for i,registro in enumerate(elements):

    empresa = browser.find_element_by_xpath(f'//*[@id="grdDocumentos"]/tbody/tr[{i+1}]/td[2]').text
        
    tipo = browser.find_element_by_xpath(f'//*[@id="grdDocumentos"]/tbody/tr[{i+1}]/td[4]').text
    
    download = browser.find_element_by_xpath(f'//*[@id="grdDocumentos"]/tbody/tr[{i+1}]/td[11]/i[2]').click()
sleep(5)

print('Downloads concluídos')
```

However, if I change to other page, the information is in two different lines. I tried [{i+2}], but didn´t work. Anybody have some hint?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JQcs.png)

Edited:
I get. I used {2*i + 1}

Comment: view the webpage source code as html to see how the structure is finally displayed on browser. ex: Mozilla Firefox -> f12

Comment: I saw the structure, but as I said it jumps two lines. And after one line, the loop stop.

Comment: if possible, please update your question with the html structure to better assist you.

Comment: Thank you for your help Shyam. I figure out.